# Why Invariant Violation, When my component in View but using statement?

Tags: javascript, react-native

This Is React Native

0.59.6

I create function to cover but not work

```
return s == '00' ? <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({
          timeCount: 'A'
        })}>
          Jangkrik
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View> : h + m + ':' + s
```

How I can resolve this, but if using Text it work if like code below :

`return s == '00' ? <Text> Jangkrik </Text> : h + m + ':' + s`

But when use Button or TouchbelOpacity is Invariant Error

Comment: please include the **full error message** when usingButton or TouchbelOpacity ++ the context where you render your `s` variable

Comment: this is my full code : https://pastebin.com/ZA9cY5Xs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formatMilliseconds` of your `TimerCountdown` component should return either **raw text** like `h + m + ':' + s` some text wrapped in a `Text` component

The returned value will be rendered inside a `Text` component ... so when you're trying to return a `TouchableOpacity` component, you get `invariant violation` error ... cause in react-native: `Text` component does not accept `TouchableOpacity` as a children ...

**Valid children for Text components are: 1. Raw Text.   2. Text component**

Answer (score 0):

Use `Text` component inside `TouchableOpacity`

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({
          timeCount: 'A'
        })}>
         <Text>Jangkrik</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: i've try that tooo <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({
          timeCount: 'A'
        })}>
          <Text>Jangkrik</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? I don't understand what you have written in else condition.

Comment: i will make resend code when the time is over is change with button resend code.

Comment: Did you mean to write something like this :
<View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({
          timeCount: 'A'
        })}>
          <Text>{ s == '00' ?'Jangkrik' : h + m + ':' + s  }</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

Comment: what you mean  : like this Avani

Comment: where the comment @avani